# How to make a mobile menu with columns in Bootstrap5?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, hamburger-menu

I have a typical bootstrap navbar that collapses to a dropdown menu on smaller devices. As default menus do, it shows a vertical list of items, which takes up too much space, so I would like to group items in two columns. Here's a drawing of what I mean:

[image: image presenting two mobile menus; one with a vertical list of items and one with items in two columns. first one is what I currently have, second is what I want to have]

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Item 1</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 3</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 4</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 5</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 6</a>
              </li>
        
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

[CodeSandbox code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-dream-719oj?file=/index.html)

I tried grouping it using `<div class="col-sm-4"> [three items] </div>` but it failed, because I misunderstood how cols work. It grouped items only on the normal navbar, leaving hamburger menu untouched. Unfortunately, all solutions I could find refer to dropdown menus, but it doesn't translate to hamburgers, or at least I can't make it work.

I have no problems using JS if it isn't possible using pure B5/HTML/CSS. Also, I'd like not to change anything in how the standard navbar works on bigger devices, it shouldn't be grouped in any way - I want those columns to be present only on a hamburger menu.

Comment: please add your code using this https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: @SuneelKumar should I just link it here or is there any way to add it directly into a post? Anyway, I linked it to the post under my code

Answer (score 1):

The content of the navbar can be dynamic and there's a lot of ways to show two columns inside the navbar menu.

As a simple solution I used the a row container and columns just to illustrate the possibilities. You can add a divider that shows in mobile which is what is drawn.

Hope this helps and answers your question.

This is just one way to do this ([codepen](https://codepen.io/shamshoum/pen/mdmaGOb?editors=1010)):

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 5</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 6</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 5</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 6</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Another possibility is just wrap the `<ul>` lists with a flex div which will also show the menu as two columns ([codepen](https://codepen.io/shamshoum/pen/LYyMJdo)). I think this is a better solution I just wanted you to have more than one possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Use the grid (row/cols) in the `navbar-nav`. Use the `row-cols-*` classes to set the number of columns. This way you won't have to split the columns in your markup.

```
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
           <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row row g-0 row-cols-2 row-cols-lg-6">
                <li class="nav-item col">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Item 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item col">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item col">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item col">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 4</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item col">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 5</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item col">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 6</a>
                </li>
           </ul>
     </div>
```

[Responsive demo](https://codeply.com/p/1lWqioT5IR)